# Naming convestions: send_autoreply() vs send_auto_reply()

Tags: methods, naming-conventions

Which method name is better, and why?

- `send_autoreply()`
- `send_auto_reply()`

Comment: Wasn't my answer helpful?

Comment: Yes, it was. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer going with `send_auto_reply()` if using *snake_case* naming convention, because:

- It helps you stick with the snake_case naming standard (it will look more like other variable/function names in your code).
- For other similar situations, there will be no grammatical concerns as always going with this simple standard guarantees you're not making a grammatical error.
- If you have an opposite function which for manual reply, then the correct name would be  `send_manual_reply()`, so it helps with consistency.